# Frequently Have to Reset SMC to turn on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, macos, power-management

So over the last 2-3 weeks my 2014 13 inch MacBook Pro has developed an issue.  I have to reset my SMC in order to power it on. This has occurred about 4-5 times. Additionally, my battery is on it's way out and is at the "Replace Soon" level.  I am not sure if this is a logic board or a battery issue.  Can anyone help diagnose the problem or come up with solution?  I am willing to buy a new battery however I'm not sure if it would be worthwhile to pay for Apple service centre to install a new battery and logic board.

Comment: I'm not sure that it can be diagnosed without access to the hardware. Maybe you need to get it serviced.

Comment: I'd "guess" it's the battery.  A third party shop should be able to do the replacement a lot cheaper than apple.  I'd let your mac connected to the charger after you shut the machine down.  I'd expect the problem will not occur when connect to the charger.